# Get Ordered quantity in admin controller using the order id and product id?

Tags: magento2, cart, sales-order

I want to get the **Ordered quantity** for each product for that order When action is being performed on any order. How can I achieve this.

**This is code:**

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Confirm\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Custom\Confirm\Model\ResourceModel\Saleslist\CollectionFactory;

/**
 * Class Payseller.
 */
class MassConfirm extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
     /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $_orderRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService
     */
    protected $_invoiceService;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction
     */
    protected $_transaction;

    protected $_order;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService $invoiceService,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderInfo,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction $transaction
    ) {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_order = $orderInfo;
        $this->_invoiceService = $invoiceService;
        $this->_transaction = $transaction;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute action.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     *
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException|\Exception
     */

    /**
     * Get seller for the product purchased.
     *
     * Nitin Pawar 9/11/16.
     */ 
    protected function _getSellersForProduct($pid)
    {   
        $collection = $this->_objectManager->create(
                'Webkul\Marketplace\Model\Product'
            )->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter(
                'mageproduct_id', 
                $pid
            );

            $count = $collection->getData();
            return $count; 

    } 

    public function execute()
    {
            /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        $wholedata = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        foreach ($wholedata['selected'] as $orderId){

         $order = $this->_orderRepository->get($orderId);
                  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $order_ = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
                                           ->load($orderId); 

                 $orderItems = $order_->getAllItems();
            foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
                    $proID = $item->getProductId();
                    $itemSku = $item->getSku();
                    echo '<br>product id: '.$proID;
                    echo '<br>product sku: '.$itemSku;
                    $sellers = $this->_getSellersForProduct($proID);
                    var_dump($sellers);
                    foreach($sellers as $seller){
                        var_dump($seller); echo '<br>';
                    }
            }
                 exit;
                $order_->setState("processing")->setStatus("processing");

                $order_->save();  

        }   
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The order has been confirm. '));
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/order/index');
    }

}
```

Here i can get the order id and product id, and i want to display the each product ordered quantity in the cart for that order.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get **Order Quantity** from `$item`

```
        $orderItems = $order_->getAllItems();
        foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
           $itemQty = $item->getQtyOrdered();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will try this and get back to you.

Comment: @NitinPawar i updated the answer kindly look at that.

Comment: `$itemQty = $item->getQtyOrdered();`  is working where as `$itemQty = $item->getQty();` gives the empty result. Thanks again.